# An alternative to Apache Tika in Java?

Tags: library, java

Do you know an alternative to Apache Tika in Java?  This library is giving me problems and I need to resolve this ASAP. I will appreciate your advice.

**Edit:** Apache Tika is a library that is used for extract text from Office (Word, Excel, etc.) or PDF files

**Edit 2:** In that sense, the alternative library has to have this features:

- Written in Java
- Be able to extract text from Office or PDF files
- It would be great if the input was a java.io.File object and the output was a String
- Built as JAR file(s)
- Published on Maven

**Edit 3:** I finally changed Tika for a simpler library using [this code](https://codezrule.wordpress.com/2010/03/24/extract-text-from-pdf-office-files-doc-ppt-xls-open-office-files-rtf-and-textplain-files-in-java/).I modified it using the last POI and PDFxStream libraries, and it worked like a charm. I will upload the result to my GitHub account whether it helps someone. Also, I will left this question open in case that alternative exists.

**Edit 4:** https://github.com/mariosotil/text-extractor

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I will change my question.

Comment: Isn't Tika used to be able to guess what is the type of the file based on its content?

Comment: @androiddeveloper Yes but for accurate results you need to add some library which a ton of other dependencies and ends up inflating your jar to oblivion. My uber jar file went from 16MB to almost 90MB just after adding `tika-parsers` library

Comment: @chx101 Do you know of any good, small libraries that can guess the type of the file based on its content? Preferably InputStream as input, instead of file path.